# How to slide toggle dropdown menu items via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code. What it does is that on click of an `li`, the dropdown for it will slide down. If another `li` beside it is clicked, another drop down menu slides down then the previous drop down slides back up.

However, if I were to click on the same `li` to "open" and "close" it, then the drop down menu will just slide down on first click, then on second click to try and "close" it, it will slide right back down again.

So the issue is that if I click on a parent link and click on it again immediately after, the drop down menu slides up, then down again. It doesn't stay "closed" or doesn't toggle.

Here is my code:

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
  $("li > ul").slideUp();
  $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle("swing"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Parent Link</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <div class="my-content">
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: Please include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I have included my html

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how is your html and css codes but this can give idea.

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
  $(".dropdown > ul").slideUp();
  $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
})
```

```css
li.dropdown > ul{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    test1
    <ul>
      <li>testa</li>
      <li>testb</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    test2
    <ul>
      <li>testc</li>
      <li>testd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was gonna suggest adding a class as well

Comment: adding a class where it would be display none and block is the easiest and I have tried that, but then you cannot transition between a display none and a display block so I wanted to go with a jquery route

Comment: i replaced addClass removeClass with slideDown slideUp

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like click parent link to slide down all child menus, when click one child menu, slide it up, then slide down others.

Please see the comment of below codes for the details:

```js
$(".dropdown > ul").click(function(e) {
  $("li > ul").slideUp(); //slide up the menu which user clicked
  $('li > ul').not($(this)).slideDown(); //slide down other menu except the one user clicked
  $(this).children("ul").slideToggle("swing");
  e.stopPropagation(); //prevents the click event from bubbling up the DOM tree
});

$(".dropdown").click(function(e) {
  $("li > ul").slideDown(); //slide down for all child ul
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Parent Link</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <div class="my-content">
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link A</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link A</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link A</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <div class="my-content">
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link B</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link B</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">dropdown link B</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```